# Lennox G40UH transformer multi fail

Tags: hvac, furnace

My Lennox GR40UH keeps burning out the 24V transformer. I'm on the third transformer in about as many days of operation over the last couple of weeks. I added A/C to the system a couple months ago. Do I need to install a transformer with a higher VA rating?

Comment: What did you connect incorrectly?

Comment: Burning out that many transformers means you are using the wrong transformer, get the right one, or there is a fault in your system that needs to be fixed.

Comment: The control board needs 3 A, 32 VAC transformer, according to the installation manual

Comment: Do you mean 32 VAC peak-center? Or 32V AC RMS?   Normal furnace transformers are 24V RMS, which is around 32V peak when rectified.